# How to determine the effect of changing a core project's scope to runtime?

Tags: maven

I have two core projects on a java platform say `Project_Api` and Project_Core. I'm using maven for dependency management. There are other projects which depend on these two projects over their parent pom(they share the same parent pom which has these two projects with compile scope). As a result developers can import and use classes directly from Core project which is an unintended behaviour.

So I want to change the scope of `Core` project to `runtime`. But I don't know and can not distinguish which projects will be affected. I made search on questions but could not find a similar situation. Is there a way to simulate or find the effect of this before making the change?

Comment: Question is unclear, but what prevents you from change scope to runtime and check result?

Comment: There are hundreds of projects which may have used core classes. As soon as I change the scope and developers get the latest version of parent pom, they will start to get compile errors. I'm trying to find a way to detect those projects without effecting their development process.

Comment: What is relation between Project_Api and Project_Core? If you want to make Project_Core runtime why do you change scope of Project_Api?

Comment: Sorry, it should be Core project. I've edited the post.

Comment: Now issue is clear to me. You want share interface to clients (hundreds of project) but you want to hide implementation. Change Core to **runtime** is right way. And the only way to check how clients build are impacted by your change is just build clients

Comment: Yes, that's the exact case.

Comment: What if you change and `mvn install` `Core` and build all other projects just locally? Thus nobody else will be harmed. Or don't you have access to all of your clients source?

Comment: We discussed that option with our deployment admin but he said that it would not be possible to check results off all failed builds manually - which may be hundreds of them- and maybe the cause of failure is not our scope change.

Comment: You could parse the build log files for a certain string that occurs at errors caused by your change and collect these occurrences in a summary file.